# I receive the error 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' while attempting to dual boot Ubuntu along with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, grub-efi

I've looked into other answers for this error, but none of them works. So, marking this question as duplicate is futile.

**Partition Details:**

[image: Partition Details Image]

**Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:**

[image: Terminal Output image]

**Output of Boot-Repair:**
https://pastebin.com/raw/V6tpA4R7

**Output of `sudo parted -l`:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVZwA.png)

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 0. I've tried both Try Ubuntu and using desktop shortcut and installing directly. No improvements.

The details of the errors and log files are [Here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1700265)

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question as a duplicate but as unclear. Please put the information in your post instead of sending us to an external site where the data is many clicks away. If you are making a bug report, your question is off-topic. All I can see in there anyway is that the NTFS partition is hibernated, and `overlay_scrollbar` doesn't want to load. As for "looking into other answers" please detail (in your question) what you have tried and how it failed. Also basic stuff, how did you do partitioning during installation? Show the output of `sudo fdisk -l`etc. Help us to help you!

Comment: Sure Zanna! Thanks for your help. I am new to this forum, so your advice helped me a lot. Kindly look at the the updates in the question description and help me.

Comment: Launchpad link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1700265

Comment: I don't know - you need one of the dual boot/UEFI pros, not me. Did the installation completely abort? Or was it partially completed? You can run boot repair and post the info summary which will be a lot more useful than all those logs you posted on Launchpad which look pretty irrelevant to me. It might help to run `ubiquity -b` to install which should allow you to skip installing the bootloader altogether, then use boot repair to get a thorough picture of what's going on.

Comment: @Zanna The installation went up to 90% or so. Then it popped up this fatal error. The installer crashed. Where do I run ubiquity -b? How do I run boot repair?

Comment: See this answer: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](//askubuntu.com/a/228069) how to use boot repair is included. The rest may also have some useful info for you. What I meant was, boot the live system, open a terminal, and type `ubiquity -b`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61096/discussion-between-benedict-florance-and-zanna).